# how to post the large data with out strong type model in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, http-post

I will get JSON objects like below formats,each format contains differnt properties/Keys i.e. these properties/keys are dynamic.

```
var SelectedRows=   [
            {"id":"1","name":"jhon","phone":"6699"},
            {"id":"2","name":"Aron","phone":"7799"},
            {"id":"3","name":"Iyan","phone":"8899"},
        ]

var SelectedRows=   [
            {"id":"1","fname":"jhon","lname":"6699"},
            {"id":"2","fname":"Aron","lname":"7799"},
            {"id":"3","fname":"Iyan","lname":"8899"},
        ]

var SelectedRows=   [
        {"id":"1","fname":"jhon","lname":"6699"},
        {"id":"2","fname":"Aron","lname":"7799"},
        {"id":"3","fname":"Iyan","lname":"8899"},
        ]
```

Posting the data using AJAX post call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Export", "Export")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(SelectedRows),
    success: function(result) {}
});​
```

Controller Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(**what type to specify here**)
{

}
```

As i said properties/keys are dynamic so i can't use the strong type model here.
I have to specifiy some genaric type of parameter for the action method.

I don't it is possible or not? if yes, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a `dynamic` type may be the answer for you.  A full detail post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object).

Comment: I tried that dynamic type, but it always showing the value of parameter as {object}. and your link explaining about deserialization of json value after receiving in action method.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(FormCollection collection)
{

}
```

More info about [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i done.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Export", "Export")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(SelectedRows),
  **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",**
    success: function(result) {}
});​
```

Need to specify the application **contentType** while the posting the data and
receive the list values of dynamic type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(**List<dynamic>** SelectedRows)
{

}
```